# Javascript V8 - How to optimally remove object property from iteration

Tags: javascript, optimization, v8

Reading that deleting values from an object substantially slows down the objects and disqualifies them from V8's hidden classes performance improvements.

What is the most optimal to hide/remove a property from an object so that it doesn't appear when you iterate over that object.

*Use case:* I am saving an object as a document to a NoSQL database and if a certain field is null I don't want it to show up at all in the database structure.

Is it faster to create a new object without the values? use `Object.defineProperty` to set the objects property to `enumerable: false`? or is there an even better way?

Comment: How could it possibly be faster to create a whole new object, and copy all but one properties to it, than to `delete myObj.property`? These micro-optimizations are really insignificant. Try to determine what part of the application has the most significant impact on it's speed, and try to improve that, instead.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Possible `delete` does create a whole new underlying object as well…

Comment: Why can't you just set it to `null` and filter out `null` values in the iteration? I don't think `enumerable:false` does anything different, but on a lower level where it needs to create heavier properties.

Comment: What kind of objects are these that may or may not have these properties? Maybe they don't benefit from hidden classes anyway…

Comment: It's sometimes faster to store data as `[[key1, value1], ...]`. The  lookup to object's fields is faster when the object is "big enough".

Comment: The objects aren't massive objects (Average 25 properties). @Bergi just setting it to null doesn't serve my purpose as some properties I want to keep as null, but not all. The objects don't use any prototypical properties but are solely just for holding data. If I were to do a check for 'if (val===null)' for 25+ properties, then that's about the equivalent of creating a new object from scratch as I'm storing the object directly into the database (into Elasticsearch)

Comment: Are all the objects having the *same* properties? But honestly I think Cerbrus is right and you should just use `delete`. If your performance is too slow, try `Object.definePoperty` and new objects, and *measure* the difference in *your setup*.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. It's not that it's slow (yet) it's more so wanting to know if there's a smarter/faster way going forward. It's a short lived object literal leading me to think more that Cerbrus is right for this use case. The properties are variadic.

Comment: If your objects are heavily variadic then hash table is the most optimal representation